# How to remotely administer Hyper-V on Windows 7 or 8.1 non-pro version?

Tags: hyper-v

I need a way of using the hyper-v management tools using Windows 7 home premium or Windows 8.1 non-pro version.
I find it ridiculous that from what I read online, you need the pro version to even use the managemnt gui.
Is there any other way to remotely administer hyper-V on a Windows Core host using Windows 7 or 8.1 home premium?

Comment: You can't because hyper-v isn't even supported on Windows 7

Comment: "I find it ridiculous that from what I read online, you need the pro version to even use the managemnt gui." Remotely managing things like Hyper-V, WMI, etc. is considered to be business-grade activities by Microsoft. If you want to do business-grade stuff, you need a business grade OS.

Comment: techie: that isn't a problem administering vmware hosts, or many other business server apps from any OS.  I guess i was giving Microsoft too much credit.  so no it's not that ridiculous to be able to manage business grade servers remotely using any operating system.

Comment: if you prefer VMWare's feature-set, then use VMware. If you like MS' stuff, then you have to follow MS' workflow.  One thing to consider is that the Hyper-V management (and other) stuff relies on Windows AD authentication before allowing the client to connect, which isn't supported by Home versions of Windows. Perhaps spend the $99 to get Pro, and your problem goes away?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to remotely administer hyper-V on a Windows Core host using Windows 7 or 8.1 home premium

RDP into a Windows Server (or to a desktop client running Pro or Enterprise) with the management tools installed on it, and manage it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after a long bit of research. This is what I've found. Problem is Microsoft changed from using MSI's which you could use Orca to delete the requirements for install allowing the RSAT tools to install on all versions whether it would work or not. They stopped that by using a cert signed update. Also adding it as an update made it install in to available features but not actually installed until you added the individual features. Because people complained of vulnerabilities by forced install of all tools. Or so Microsoft says.

The only slight possibility would be this;

First open up by expanding, 
`expand -f:* "Windows6.1-KB958830-x64-RefreshPkg.msu" %temp%\RSAT`

Use something to modify the update.mum in the Windows6.1-KB958830-x64-RefreshPkg.cab file. But even if you did I wouldn't know how to force windows to take an update thats been altered.

If you get that done by miracle, then you can run it. 
`pkgmgr.exe /n:%temp%\RSAT\Windows6.1-KB958830-x64.xml`

If you find a way to complete this bit of awesome let the whole world know. People have wanted it for years.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can completely administer Hyper-V through PowerShell.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848559.aspx
http://windowsitpro.com/hyper-v/manage-hyperv-powershell